# PL/SQL CREATE PROCEDURE - factorial

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't know what's wrong with my code block to create a procedure to find out the factorial of a number. Thank you.

Question 1: write a stored procedure that gets an integer number n and calculates and displays its factorial.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE factorial_number(
    n NUMBER) AS
    factorial NUMBER;
    num Number;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN REVERSE 1..n LOOP
    num := i - 1;
    factorial := factorial * num;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (factorial);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error!');
END;
/
BEGIN
    factorial_number(5);
END;
/
```

Comment: Best way to debug your code is to put dbms_output statements inside of your loop so you see what is happening at each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're failing to initialize the local variable `factorial`.  Uninitialized variables are initially `null` and multiplying `null` by any value produces `null`.
2. I don't see why you'd want your loop to go in reverse order.  It doesn't matter since multiplication is communitive but it it unlikely to make your code easier to read/ debug/ follow.
3. You don't want to subtract 1 from the value you are multiplying by on each iteration of the loop.  When `i = 1`, for example, you're multiplying `factorial` by 0 which means that (assuming you initialize `factorial`), you'd always end up with 0.  You want to multiply by `i` so there is no need for the local variable `num`.

If I make those fixes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE factorial_number(
    n NUMBER) 
AS
    factorial NUMBER := 1;  -- Initialize
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..n LOOP -- Loop normally
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Beginning iteration ' || i || ' of loop. ' ||
                            'Factorial = ' || factorial ||
                            ' multiplying by ' || i );
      factorial := factorial * i; -- Multiply by i not i-1
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (factorial);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error!');
END;
```

Then

```
BEGIN
    factorial_number(5);
END;
```

will print out 120 (`5*4*3*2*1`).

I'm also adding an additional `dbms_output` line to print out the current state of the variables on each iteration of the loop.  That's a relatively old-school method of debugging.  In the modern world, you'd walk through the code with a debugger where you can see the values of your local variables but introductory classes may not teach debugger usage initially.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much for your thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE factorial_number (n NUMBER)
  2  AS
  3     factorial  NUMBER := 1;
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i IN 1 .. n
  6     LOOP
  7        factorial := factorial * i;
  8     END LOOP;
  9
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (factorial);
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL>


SQL> BEGIN
  2     factorial_number (5);
  3  END;
  4  /
120

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Presumably you can remove the `num` local variable since you're no longer using it.

Comment: Obviously; thank you, @Justin.